# how to use defferd for asynchronous event handling in twsited

Tags: python, asynchronous, twisted

I have a client and this client shoud read server event. I want to know how can I make this code asynchronous. I see the defferd example but I didn't get how to use It for incoming event  in the correct way.

```
class EchoClient(protocol.Protocol):


    def dataReceived(self, data):
        d = Deferred()
        d.addCallback(self.incoming_event)
        d.callback(data)

    def incoming_event(self,data):
        #some thing



class EchoFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):
    protocol = EchoClient
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app
    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        print "Connection failed."
        reactor.stop()
    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        print "Connection lost."
        reactor.stop()
```

when I have lot's of event the processing of this event is one by one and I need them to process together. is there any twisted way? or I need to put them in regular theread?

Comment: There's nothing in your example code that needs to be made asynchronous.  The rest of your question doesn't give much hint about what you're trying to accomplish or where you got stuck, either.  I think you will need to expand the question before anyone can give you a helpful answer.

Comment: I extend my question, I have a gui application that use twisted to update widget . when I have lots of event in dataReceived the processing of this event is one by one . I want to know is there any twisted way to do this?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twisted is a cooperative multitasking system.  It offers some support for multithreading but any multithreading must be used explicitly.  Single-threaded multitasking systems do not run multiple things concurrently.  They can't.  This is part of their strength (multithreaded programmers are harder to write, understand, and debug).

Many, many, many Twisted-based programs are single threaded and work just fine.  You haven't explained why it's a problem that events in your program are handled one by one.

I could guess that perhaps it's because there are a lot of them in a short period of time and processing them gets in the way of keeping the GUI updated.  If this is the case then perhaps you could solve the problem by raising the priority of GUI events (Gtk lets you do this) or imposing some artificial limit on how many non-GUI events are processed at once.